# jMockit unexpected execution of real method in mocked object

Tags: java, unit-testing, nullpointerexception, mocking, jmockit

i have a test code (using jmockit 1.8):

```
public class BasicTest {
    ...
    @Mocked("evaluateAlternateTerms")
    WMSTK_BLT_Services wmstkBltServices;    
    @Before
    public void setUp() {...}

    @Test
    public void testAlternativeDatesCalculationException() throws Throwable {
        new Expectations() {{
            withSameInstance(capacityService);
            withSameInstance(buchungs);
            Deencapsulation.invoke(wmstkBltServices, "evaluateAlternateTerms", CapacityService.class, List.class);
            result = new KVWSException(new ErrorCode(1)) {
                public String getMessage() {
                    return "TEST";
                }
            };
        }};
        KapazitaetAendernResponse result = alternativeDates(capacityService, buchungs);

        assertThat(result.getFehlercode(), is((short) 9999));
        assertThat(result.getFehlertext(), is("TEST"));
    }
```

i'm trying to use mocked method "evaluateAlternateTerms", but it sends a error:
`java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.tsystems.kvws.WMSTK_BLT_Services.evaluateAlternateTerms(WMSTK_BLT_Services.java:87)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.tsystems.kvws.tests.wmstkKapazitaetsservices.alternativeDates.BasicTest$1.(BasicTest.java:81)
    at com.tsystems.kvws.tests.wmstkKapazitaetsservices.alternativeDates.BasicTest.testAlternativeDatesCalculationException(BasicTest.java:78)`
Why?? I did the mock, it mustn't go to: 
`evaluateAlternateTerms(WMSTK_BLT_Services.java:87)`

P.S. This is the alternativeDates method:

```
private KapazitaetAendernResponse alternativeDates(CapacityService capacityService, List kapResBuchungs) throws Throwable {
        return (KapazitaetAendernResponse) PrivateAccessor.invoke(new WmstkKapazitaetsservices(),
                "alternativeDates", new Class[] {CapacityService.class, List.class}, 
                new Object[] {capacityService, kapResBuchungs});
    }
```

Thanks in advance!